# How to Stop the prompt window - The file is executable. Do you want to execute it?

Tags: python, linux, raspbian-jessie

I created an executable file (say- TestApp) from a python file using pyinstaller. Everything works fine. But every time, if try to open it, this Prompt window will appear. [The file is executable. Do you want to execute it]. It is a bit annoying. Is it possible to stop showing this prompt window and open the TestApp directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer from [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/840600) should work.

- Open PCManFM
- Go to Edit/Preferences/General
- Check box for "Don't ask options on launch executable file"